# Execute function on real page refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

Is there any way to only execute a function in the controller on the page refresh instead of going the another ng-view?

I got a view with items in a list. When I click on one of the items it goes to a detail page where I pass the data to a service and get it back on the detail page, so I dont have to call another $http request for getting the single item data.

This works, but when I hit f5 I want to execute a function to execute a $http request to get the item data. When I hit f5, of course the data isn't in the service anymore.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The id of the item should be in the url, then in the resolve of the view you can specify to get the data of the item from $http, based on id in the url/routeParams or $stateParams if you're using ui-router.

Comment: Can you make a quick code-block? I'm not sure what u mean. I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I havent written it because I'm not sure what you need :) Do you have some snippets from your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is that in your route / path / url, you need to add the ID or unique property that identifies the item whose detail that you are checking out.

So, let us say that you are on the path `/template/items`.

When the user selects item 2, you then change the path to `/template/item/2`.

In your `$routeProvider` have the route defined as:

`$routeProvider.when('/template/item/:itemId', {..});`

The `itemId` will provide the ID associated with the item.
In the controller, using `$routeParams` you can then read this ID  using `$routeParams.itemId`.
Query your service and see if it has details of this item with it. If not, then proceed with the `$http` request.

That way, even if you refresh your screen, the Item ID is still present in the url from which your controller can retrieve it and carry out the appropriate action.

Comment: Im not sure what u mean. At the moment I just got a check on my $scope variable. When its undefined it executes the $http request. Otherwise it will get it from the service.

Comment: Check your route that loads the page and the controller. You need to redefine your route url to include the item ID in the controller.